# How to make my section float from one page onto the next?

Tags: tabularx, sharelatex, cv

I'm writing a resume/cv for my future nursing occupation in NYC area and one of my sections of keeps falling off onto the next page when I compile it, leaving my first page basically empty. I do not know what to search for in google or what sequence of commands I need to type in to tell LaTex to stop doing this. I found the code on ShareLatex and have modified it since, furthermore I have omitted some of my personal information because reasons. The code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip, tabularx}     %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
%\font\wm=''Baskerville:color=787878'' at 8pt
%\font\wmweb=''Baskerville:color=FF1493'' at 8pt
%{\wm 
%   \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
%       \rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{500mm}{
%           Typeset by Alessandro Plasmati with \XeTeX\  \today\ for 
%           {\wmweb \href{http://www.aleplasmati.comuv.com}{aleplasmati.comuv.com}}
%       }
%   }
%   \end{textblock}
%}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE------------- 
\par{\centering
        {\Huge{Viengkham} \Huge{Vongsay}
    }\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data

\section{Personal Information}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Birth place:} & Location \\
    \textsc{Date of Birth:} & Birth date\\
    \textsc{Permanent Address:}   &  Location\\

    \textsc{Phone:}     & Number\\
    \textsc{Email:}     & \href{email@gmail.com}{email@gmail.com} \\
    \textsc{Fluent Spoken Languages:} & Langues \\
    \textsc{Florida Registered Nurse License Number:} & # \\
    \textsc{New York Registered Nurse License Number:} & #
\end{tabular}

% Section: Objective statement

\section{Objective}
 \begin{tabular}{l}
    Joining a medical organization dedicated to delivering quality healthcare in a professional \\ setting.
\end{tabular}

% Section: Qualifications
```

FYI this is the location where it bumps into the next page, making me very annoyed

```
% Section: Work Experience

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
% most recent occupation
 \emph{Current} & Registered Nurse at Post Anesthesia Care Unit in Memorial Hospital in Jacksonville Florida  \\\textsc{2008}&
 \footnotesize{
 \\&\textbf{A. Pre-op}
\\&\footnotesize{
\textbullet{Verification of patients, surgical procedure, medications allergies, vital signs and laboratory values}}
\\&\footnotesize{
\textbullet{Facilitate all parameters to safeguard a safe transition to surgical suit}}

\\&
\textbf{B. Post-op}
\\&\footnotesize{
\textbullet{Recover post-op surgical patients while working closely with anesthesia doctors to keep each patient in a stable and comfortable environment}}
\\&\footnotesize{
\textbullet{Airway and cardiac monitoring}}
\\& \footnotesize{
\textbullet{Verification of all STAT post op orders}}
\\&\footnotesize{
\textbullet{Obtaining all necessary parameters}}
\\&\footnotesize{
\textbullet{Transfer or admitting patients once stabilized}}
\\& \footnotesize{
\textbullet{Supervision of all discharge parameters and education before patient is discharged home or to the floor}
}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
% second most recent occupation
 \textsc{2005 - 2008} & Registered Nurse on Medical/Surgical Unit at Memorial Hospital in Jacksonville Florida \\& Routine management of medical and surgical patients and communication with the other healthcare providers.\\& \footnotesize{
 \textbullet{Ongoing learning in daily nursing practice detailed to clinical reasoning, critical thinking, judgment, and decision making as appropriate.}}\\& \footnotesize{
 \textbullet{Collaborate with other members of healthcare team including, but not limited to, the physician, involved nurses, respiratory therapist, and physical therapists, compassion and support for each individual client.}}
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
% third most recent occupation
 \textsc{2004 - 2005} & Clinical Nurse in surgical unit at Mercy Hospital in Portland Maine.\\&
 \footnotesize{\textbullet{Tailor nursing care practice to each individual patient and family as needed}}\\&
 \footnotesize{\textbullet{Provide care for post-surgical patients to help them achieve optimal recovery}}
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
% fourth most recent occupation 
  \textsc{2001 - 2004} & Clinical Nurse in surgical unit at Maine Medical Center in Portland Maine.\\&
  \footnotesize{\textbullet{Work with many members of the healthcare team to provide care for the patient.}}\\&
  \footnotesize{\textbullet{Recover many different types of surgical patients, abdominal aortic aneurysm, thoractormy, cartoid, fem-pop, and any other type of vascular surgery}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
% fifth most recent occupation  
  \textsc{1991 - 2000} & Business Owner Vientiane Market in Portland Maine \\&\footnotesize{
  Purchase specialty items, Hiring
  } \multicolumn{2}{c}{} 
% should you wish to add any content to the second through fifth occupations you need to type \footnotesize{} and type as you please within the brackets. 
\end{tabular}

%Section: Education

\section{Education}
\begin{tabular}{rl} 
% most recent academic certification
 \textsc{1995 - 2000} & University of Southern Maine  \\&\footnotesize{\emph{Bachelor of Science in Nursing}
}

\end{tabular}

\section{Volunteer and Extra Curicular Activities}
\begin{tabular}{l1}
\textbullet{Celebrate Asia Jacksonville 2012 and 2013} 
\end{tabular}

% Section: Skills/Abilities

\section{Skills and Abilities}
\begin{tabular}{l1}
\textbullet{Provide Excellent and compassionate care for patients in the past sixteen years as a clinical nurse.} \\

\textbullet{Excellent communication skills with patients and co-workers.} \\

\textbullet{Committed to  consistent above line of duty performance} 

\end{tabular}



%\XeTeXpdffile ''GMAT.pdf'' page 1 scaled 800

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try replacing your tabular with an itemize.  It will break across pages.  tabulars won't (longtable will).

Comment: that worked, but now my formatting is all screwed up! sorry for the possible noob question

Comment: Split your stuff in different `tabular`  environments.

Comment: That's not very much a solution, that'd also not work with the formatting. Is there no simple way to tell LaTex "hey I just want this tabular to start on one page and end on the next"?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reformat your document using a list.  To make it act more like a tabular I precomputed the indentation.  One difference is that the `\textbullet` is now in the left column.  You can fix that by nesting another itemize inside an `\item`, although you may need to recompute `\leftmarginii`.

Note that each `\item` can be followed by multiple paragraphs using normal formatting commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{showframe}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\begin{document}

\section{Personal Information}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Birth place:} & Location \\
    \textsc{Date of Birth:} & Birth date\\
    \textsc{Permanent Address:}   &  Location\\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & Number\\
    \textsc{Email:}     & \href{email@gmail.com}{email@gmail.com} \\
    \textsc{Fluent Spoken Languages:} & Langues \\
    \textsc{Florida Registered Nurse License Number:} & \# \\
    \textsc{New York Registered Nurse License Number:} & \#
\end{tabular}

% Section: Objective statement

\section{Objective}
    Joining a medical organization dedicated to delivering quality healthcare in a professional setting.

% Section: Work Experience

\section{Work Experience}

\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \emph{Current} \\
  \textsc{2005 - 2008} \\
  \textsc{2004 - 2005} \\
  \textsc{2001 - 2004}
\end{tabular}}% compute width of first column
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr \labelwidth + 2\labelsep - \bibindent}% set indentation

\begin{itemize}
% most recent occupation
\item[\emph{Current}]
   Registered Nurse at Post Anesthesia Care Unit in Memorial Hospital in Jacksonville Florida  \\
   \textsc{2008}

\item[]{\footnotesize\textbf{A. Pre-op}}
\item \footnotesize{Verification of patients, surgical procedure, medications allergies, vital signs and laboratory values}
\item \footnotesize{Facilitate all parameters to safeguard a safe transition to surgical suit}

\item[] \textbf{B. Post-op}
\item \footnotesize{Recover post-op surgical patients while working closely with anesthesia doctors
 to keep each patient in a stable and comfortable environment}
\item \footnotesize{Airway and cardiac monitoring}
\item \footnotesize{Verification of all STAT post op orders}
\item \footnotesize{Obtaining all necessary parameters}
\item \footnotesize{Transfer or admitting patients once stabilized}
\item \footnotesize{Supervision of all discharge parameters and education before patient is discharged home or to the floor}
% second most recent occupation
\item[\textsc{2005 - 2008}] Registered Nurse on Medical/Surgical Unit at Memorial Hospital in Jacksonville Florida \\
  Routine management of medical and surgical patients and communication with the other healthcare providers.
\item \footnotesize{Ongoing learning in daily nursing practice detailed to clinical reasoning, critical thinking, judgment, and decision making as appropriate.}
\item \footnotesize{Collaborate with other members of healthcare team including, but not limited to, the physician, involved nurses, respiratory therapist, and physical therapists, compassion and support for each individual client.}

\pagebreak[3]
% third most recent occupation
\item[\textsc{2004 - 2005}] Clinical Nurse in surgical unit at Mercy Hospital in Portland Maine.
\item \footnotesize{Tailor nursing care practice to each individual patient and family as needed}
\item \footnotesize{Provide care for post-surgical patients to help them achieve optimal recovery}

% fourth most recent occupation 
\item[\textsc{2001 - 2004}] Clinical Nurse in surgical unit at Maine Medical Center in Portland Maine.
\item \footnotesize{Work with many members of the healthcare team to provide care for the patient.}
\item \footnotesize{Recover many different types of surgical patients, abdominal aortic aneurysm, thoractormy, cartoid, fem-pop, and any other type of vascular surgery}

% fifth most recent occupation  
\item[\textsc{1991 - 2000}] Business Owner Vientiane Market in Portland Maine \\
\footnotesize{Purchase specialty items, Hiring}
% should you wish to add any content to the second through fifth occupations you need to type \footnotesize{} and type as you please within the brackets. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```